# In MySql how to replicate specific tables with two different databases?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-replication

We have a situation in which we need to have two separate databases, DB1 has X number of tables and DB2 has 4 tables in which 3 of them must be synced with DB1, so that no matter we update these 3 tables from DB1 or DB2 it synced with each other. fourth table would be specific to DB2 only.

Comment: This would really be a better question for [dba.se], but I believe the answer Alex gave you is what you need...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [replicate-ignore-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-ignore-table) configuration option.